# Check if blob exists

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to build a DAG that first checks if a given path/blob in the Google Cloud Storage exists. The blob is the one containing some RAW data and is not the one mounted on the Composer workers.

Alternatively, it would be convenient to see if it exists and contains files (list > 1) in one go, but existance is already a good thing to get back.

So far I tried using both the gsutil stats through a bash command, the google.cloud.storage library and the gcs_hook to no avail. All of them return False for a folder I'm quite certain exists

```py
def check_folder(templates_dict,**kwargs):
    bucket = 'bucketname'
    blob_name = templates_dict['blob_name']
    # Blob name is something along the lines of '2019-04-10/11/' 
    gcs = GoogleCloudStorageHook()
    flag = gcs.exists(bucket,blob_name)
    if flag:
        print(flag)
        return('this_is_true')
    else:
        print(flag)
        return('this_is_not_true')
```

For a given blob_name, that I am quite sure exists, I am expecting a true, but it always returns False. Any idea what is going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exists` function in `GoogleCloudStorageHook` checks for an object and doesn't support the use of prefixes. If you want to check if there is any data in your given prefix you would want to use the `list` function.

Example:

```
if bool(hook.list(bucket, prefix=prefix)):
    print('some data is in my folder!')
```

You may also want to check out the implementation of the Sensor [GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor.py#L123) as it is very similar to what you are doing.